# In how many ways can you sit 12 men and 12 women on a bench, so that no 2 women sit next to each other

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can you sit 12 men and 12 women on a bench, so that no 2 women sit next to each other?
There are 2 possible ways to sit them:
**1** - In the first sit (from the left) sits a man, and then a woman, men, woman ... until the last (24'th) sit that's occupied by a man.
**2** - In the first sit (from the left) sits a woman, and then a man, woman, man... until the last (24'th) sit that's occupied by a woman.
So my answer was $2\cdot12!\cdot12!$ but apparently it's incorrect beause the book says $13!\cdot12!$
What did I do wrong? My answer looks ok to me :(

Comment: As mentioned in the other post, your answer incorrectly assumes that it must be alternating man-woman-man-woman or alternating woman-man-woman-man, however it is possible for two men to sit next to one another if women sit on both far ends.  Your count does not take this into account.  Consider the question for two men and two women.  You have the possibilities mWmW, WmWm, WmmW.